# Error 1 'OrdLista': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type C:

Tags: c#

I've seen this answered before but I cant' make any sene out of this so I really hope someone can slap me in the face and show me what i don't understand.

> **Error 1**   `OrdLista`: member names cannot be the same as their enclosing
>   type  C:

```
class OrdLista
    {
        //Detta är ordlistan för de förutbestämda orden som kommer att finnas utöver det som spelaren skapar själv

        private List<string> ord = new List<string>();
        public void OrdLista()
        {
            //Det förutbestämda ordet i det här spelet är "projektarbete" och endast ett ord kommer att användas.
            ord.Add("projektarbete"); //ord.add lägger till fler ord.
            ord.Sort();
            foreach (string word in ord)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(word);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HängaGubbe
{

```
class Meny
{

    static void main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //_____________________________________MENY_____________________________________________________
            //Detta är menyn, de första två raderna är introduktionen
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tVälkommen, dags att hänga gubben!\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nRegler: Lägg till egna ord eller spela med slumpmässiga!\n\n");

            //Nu kommer menyn, spelaren har fyra (4) alternativ att välja på.
            // 1 Öppnar för spelaren att lägga till egna ord till spelet
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\t 1 Lägg till egna ord");
            // 2 Visar alla förutbestämda ord som finns i spelet
            Console.WriteLine("\t 2 Lista alla förbestämda ord");
            // 3 är alternativet spela
            Console.WriteLine("\t 3 Spela!");
            //4 Avslutar spelet
            Console.WriteLine("\t 4 Avsluta");
            //Instruktionen som ber spelaren att välka alternativ 1-4
            Console.WriteLine("\t Välj något av alternativen 1-4!");

            string menyVal = Console.ReadLine();

            //__________________________________Alternativ 1: SPELAR ORD_________________________________
            if (menyVal == "1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tLägg till egna ord! Max 5st");
                // 5 ord som max, för att utöka lägg till fler och fortsätt i nummerordningen.
                string[] ordLista = new string[10];
                ordLista[0] = Console.ReadLine();
                ordLista[1] = Console.ReadLine();
                ordLista[2] = Console.ReadLine();
                ordLista[3] = Console.ReadLine();
                ordLista[4] = Console.ReadLine();


                // Slumpvalt ord
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tKan du gissa rätt?");
                Random randGen = new Random();
                var idx = randGen.Next(0, 4);
                string hemligt = ordLista[idx];

                char[] gissatOrd = new char[hemligt.Length];
                char gissa;
                bool rättOrd = false;
                Program kontroll = new Program();
                for (int i = 0; i < gissatOrd.Length; i++)
                {
                    gissatOrd[i] = '*';
                }

                Console.Write("\n\n\t");
                for (int i = 0; i < gissatOrd.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(gissatOrd[i]);
                }


                Console.WriteLine("\n\t*****************************");
                while (!rättOrd)
                {

                    Console.Write("\n\tVälj en bokstav från A till Ö");
                    gissa = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

                    kontroll.ordKontroll(hemligt, gissatOrd, gissa);
                    rättOrd = kontroll.rättaOrd(hemligt, gissatOrd);

                    Console.WriteLine("\n\t*****************************");

                }


            }

            //__________________________ALTERNATIV 2: ORDLISTA___________________________

            else if (menyVal == "2")
            {
                //Anrop till ordlisatn
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tOrdlista\n");
                OrdLista showing = new OrdLista();
                showing.Ordlista();

            }


             //__________________________ALTERNATIV 3: SPELA___________________________

            else if (menyVal == "3")
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tLycka till nu kompis!");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tVilket ord letar vi efter?");

                    //Förbestämda ord
                    string[] ordLista = new string[10];
                    ordLista[0] = "projektarbete";


                    //Slumpade ord
                    Random randGen = new Random();
                    var idx = randGen.Next(0, 2);
                    string hemligtOrd = ordLista[idx];
                    char[] gissatOrd = new char[hemligtOrd.Length];
                    char gissa;
                    bool rättaOrd = false;
                    Program kontroll = new Program();
                    for (int i = 0; i < gissatOrd.Length; i++)
                    {
                        gissatOrd[i] = '*';
                    }

                    Console.Write("\n\n\t");
                    for (int i = 0; i < gissatOrd.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(gissatOrd[i]);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tGissa på en bokstav!");
                    while (!rättaOrd)
                    {
                        Console.Write("\nVälj en bokstav från A till Ö:");
                        gissa = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

                        kontroll.ordKontroll(hemligtOrd, gissatOrd, gissa);
                        rättaOrd = kontroll.rättaOrd(hemligtOrd, gissatOrd);
                    }




                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\tTryck på valfri knapp för att återgå\n\n");
                    Console.ReadKey();

                    break;

                }
            }
            //__________________________ALTERNATIV 4: Avsluta___________________________

            else if (menyVal == "4")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tTack för att du ville spela och välkommen åter!\n\n\n\n");
                break;
            }
        }

    }


}
```

}

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Error 1 'HängaGubbe.OrdLista' does not contain a definition for 'Ordlista' and no extension method 'Ordlista' accepting a first argument of type 'HängaGubbe.OrdLista' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) this is what i get if i remove void..


Sorry, did not paste the whole. its now in there

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for being slow. How do i do that? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class is named `OrdLista` and you also have a method `public void OrdLista()` if this should be the constructor of your class, you need to remove the `void` .

A constructor has a scope (here `public`) and the Classname follwed by zero or multiple parameters.

EDIT: As it seems OrdaLista.OrdaLista() should be a method and no constructor, rename the method to something **different** but still meaningful and readd the void.

EDIT 2: How you should do this:

```
class OrdLista
{
    //Detta är ordlistan för de förutbestämda orden som kommer att finnas utöver det som spelaren skapar själv

    private List<string> ord = new List<string>();
    public void OrdListaToConsole()
    {
        //Det förutbestämda ordet i det här spelet är "projektarbete" och endast ett ord kommer att användas.
        ord.Add("projektarbete"); //ord.add lägger till fler ord.
        ord.Sort();
        foreach (string word in ord)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        }
    }

}
```

and then you call it like:

```
OrdLista showing = new OrdLista();
showing.OrdListaToConsole();
```

Note: you don't have any items in the list `ord`, only "projektarbete" .

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for being slow. How do i do that? :)

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems to help, now next trouble dawned om me: Error 1 Program '\Hänga_Gubbe_Projetk_140716\obj\x86\Debug\Hänga_Gubbe_Projetk_140716.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point Hänga_Gubbe_Projetk_140716

What does this mean?

Comment: As your first question is answered, please ask a new question. You can post a link to this question if you want.