# .exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point Hänga_Gubbe_Projetk_140716

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point   Hänga_Gubbe_Projetk_140716, I don't understand this att all, is there someone out there who can help me out?

Link to a previous question i had, contains code.

[Error 1 'OrdLista': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type C:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781770/error-1-ordlista-member-names-cannot-be-the-same-as-their-enclosing-typec)

Answer (score 1):

Your program needs an entry point. Add something like this:

```
class TestClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx